# How to get/query creation time of account in mongodb?? (inserted data with monogo_db_plugin)

Tags: database, full-node

I'm syncing with mongo_db_plugin enabled.
But, when I see 'acctounts' collection in mongo, createAt is time created in monogo, not actual eos mainnet.

How can I query mongo to get accounts creation time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no such data in the mongodb directly.

You could use the RPC API, which is `POST v1/chain/get_account` with `account_name` field. Like this:

```
 curl --request POST --url https://api.eosbean.com/v1/chain/get_account --data '{"account_name":"eosbeaneosbp"}'
```

If you really want to retrieve that data from mongodb, you could query the `action_traces` collection, and look for documents where `act.name` is `newaccount` and `act.data.name` is the account you are looking for.